# Como enviar 2 send a un servlet por el metodo post

Tags: javascript, ajax, aplicación-web, servlets

Quisiera poder obtener su ayuda! estoy queriendo cargar una grilla y una lista desplegable en mi pagina HTML, lo estoy haciendo desde javascript pero teniendo como controlador un servlet ya que es un proyecto didáctico, el problema surge cuando en el servlet tengo un switch con la variable bandera, y al cargar mi pagina y llamar a los metodos cargarGrillaMenuitem y cargarComboMenu ambos se envían por el metodo POST pero en el servlet primero recibo la respuesta de uno y luego al recibir del otro mi variable se encima, les paso mi codigo para que entiendan mejor.
este es mi JS:

```
cargarGrillaMenuItem();
cargarComboMenu();

function cargarGrillaMenuItem() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(), //
            method = "POST",
            url = "/seguro_medico/MenuitemCTR";
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
            //alert(xhr.responseText);
            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); //reponseText returns the entire JSON file and we assign it to a javascript variable "json".
            var i;
            var valorTabla = "";
            for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

                //mecanismo para cargar tabla
                valorTabla += "<tr onclick=\"recuperarDeGrilla(" + json[i].id + " ,'" + json[i].nombre + "', '" + json[i].url + "', " + json[i].menu.id + " , 'menuitem_id' , 'menuitem_nombre','menuitem_url','comboMenu')\">" +
                        "<td>" + json[i].id + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + json[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + json[i].url + "</td>" +
                        "<td class=\"w3-hide\">" + json[i].menu.id + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + json[i].menu.nombre + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>";
            }
            document.getElementById("cuerpoTablaMenu").innerHTML = valorTabla;
        }
    };
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(datos = {bandera: 6}));
}

function cargarComboMenu() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(), //
            method = "POST",
            url = "/seguro_medico/MenuitemCTR";
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
            //alert(xhr.responseText);
            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); //reponseText returns the entire JSON file and we assign it to a javascript variable "json".
            var i;
            var valorOption = "";
            for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                //mecanismo para cargar lista desplegable
                valorOption += "<option value=" + json[i].id + ">" + json[i].nombre + "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("comboMenu").innerHTML = valorOption;
        }
    };
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(datos = {bandera: 5}));
}
```

y este es el servlet:

```
package Controlador;

import Genericos.Metodos_genericos;
import Seguro.Dao.MenuDAO;
import Seguro.Dao.MenuitemDAO;
import Seguro.Dto.MenuDTO;
import Seguro.Dto.MenuitemDTO;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MenuitemCTR extends HttpServlet {

    private MenuitemDTO dto;
    private MenuitemDAO dao;
    private MenuDTO menuDto;
    private Gson gson;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            System.out.println("Llegamos al controlador");
            String cadenaJSON = Metodos_genericos.deRequestToJson(request);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(cadenaJSON);//se convierte el JsonElement que viene de la cadena Json a JsonObject
            Integer menuid;
            gson = new Gson();
            dto = gson.fromJson(cadenaJSON, MenuitemDTO.class);
            dao = new MenuitemDAO();
            menuDto = new MenuDTO();
//        menuDto.setId(dto.getMenu());
            System.out.println("bandera en CTR: " + dto.getBandera());
            switch (dto.getBandera()) {
                case 1:
                    menuid = jsonObject.getInt("menu_id");//se le asigna el valor de menu_id a una variable int
                    menuDto.setId(menuid);//se le setea al ID en menu_DTO
                    dto.setMenu(menuDto);//MenuDTO se le setea a setMenu
                    if (dao.agregar(dto)) {
                        // Operación Existosa => al cliente
                    } else {
                        // Operación Erronea => al cliente

                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    menuid = jsonObject.getInt("menu_id");//se le asigna el valor de menu_id a una variable int
                    menuDto.setId(menuid);//se le setea al ID en menu_DTO
                    dto.setMenu(menuDto);
                    if (dao.modificar(dto)) {
                        // Operación Existosa => al cliente
                    } else {
                        // Operación Erronea => al cliente
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (dao.eliminar(dto)) {
                        // Operación Existosa => al cliente
                    } else {
                        // Operación Erronea => al cliente
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    String json = gson.toJson(dao.seleccionarSegunId(dto));
                    if (json != null) {
                        System.out.println("Json " + json);
                        response.setContentType("application/json, charset=UTF-8");
                        out.println("[" + json + "]");
                        out.close();
                    } else {
                        out.println("");
                        out.close();
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    response.setContentType("application/json, charset=UTF-8");
                    MenuDAO daoMenu = new MenuDAO();
                    String cadenaMenu = gson.toJson(daoMenu.seleccionarTodos());
                    if (cadenaMenu != null) {
                        //enviar al js la cadena
                        System.out.println("Cadena combo" + cadenaMenu);
                        out.println(cadenaMenu);
                    } else {
                        //enviar alguna respuesta para indicar error
                    }
                    break;
                case 6:
                    //seleccionarTodos < menuitemsistema>
                    response.setContentType("application/json, charset=UTF-8");
                    String cadenaMenuItem = gson.toJson(dao.seleccionarTodos());
                    if (cadenaMenuItem != null) {
                        //enviar al js la cadena 
                        System.out.println("Cadena Grilla" + cadenaMenuItem);
                        out.println(cadenaMenuItem);
                        out.close();
                    } else {
                        //enviar alguna respuesta para indicar error
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError();
            }
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MenuitemCTR.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

como explique, mi problema esta que al cargar la pagina se activan ambas funciones en el js pero se sobreescribe mi variable bandera, ya he probado metodo como llamar uno al cargar la pagina y luego llamar al otro despues de 30 segundos pero de igual forma me sigue sobreescribiendo. Desde ya muchas gracias!